# Scraping html content that appears only when clicking on a btn

Tags: python, web-scraping, dynamic

I'm trying to scrape from the following website:
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/800ce197af8a1a277ec314daba9c0b59c3ceee0f5beec415f5b8d54a3a9db96c

all the items associated with the following class
'sc-19pxzmk-0 lhmncg'
basically that's all the addresses in a given transaction of bitcoin, but as you can see at the right side of the page there is an element :

```
<a class="sc-1r996ns-0 AqGqw sc-1tbyx6t-1 kXxRxe iklhnl-0 boNhIO" opacity="1">Load more outputs... (1 remaining)</a>
```

such that if you click on it shows another address, how can I open it dynamically? what I have tried so far is -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


output_class = 'sc-19pxzmk-0 lhmncg'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/800ce197af8a1a277ec314daba9c0b59c3ceee0f5beec415f5b8d54a3a9db96c')
result = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(output_class)
inputs = soup.find_all('div', {'class': output_class})
```

nither the beautiful soup returns the extra address nor the driver.

Comment: Did you review the results of a search using `python web page button click to get content site:stackoverflow.com` - I imagine your question is a duplicate of one of those. Please pick one and vote to close your question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If you use selenium, you didn't need to use Beautifulsoup to get the data. Use `element.click()` to click the element directly and get result directly.

```
from selenium import webdriver

output_class = 'sc-19pxzmk-0 lhmncg'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/800ce197af8a1a277ec314daba9c0b59c3ceee0f5beec415f5b8d54a3a9db96c')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".azsi2v-2").click()

result_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".sc-19pxzmk-0")

for item in result_list:
    print(item.find_element_by_css_selector("a").get_attribute("href"))
```

This gave me:

```
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1DC6cb6mFcTgJAwFDEB65Qn457BzDxs3Wh
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3JRj8b1cngQ1nJHwVPRXj1NFXRVzhMDFTf
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3PdareoJL1N8t2BQAnKcVqkS9cdQQo6gLY
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3LhFL4QhhSdtwuPBK4rwD2Z7VwndGVeoKR
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3Nyhd9vMKxep6QhquDSea7yPg9TpCAKTEF
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/12a5iTzFRJGZ4H3sZV6UZv6GrUTiwyKyR6
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3K4Hh5LDyqdryj7Xd1FBNgheE2aQHee97X
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3CeQRAViNuqXHH3AcjmdnArCEbRRAdyxCm
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1KHfhqk78kaSf5t1eC48pyLuxPHYTDstcK
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1QKfADjViFcwjCjkmwK84oPXVNNRRDY9VK
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/bc1qt0pa5a7j5ay5slqxeujjvxs6zyq7l5z0lf97flxge2std02pfdyqkwlhv4
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to press any element of a website, you can use `click()` of `find_element_by_xpath`. So for the element you mentioned, you can use the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='sc-1r996ns-0 AqGqw sc-1tbyx6t-1 kXxRxe iklhnl-0 boNhIO']").click()
```

Then when you look at the page source, it will already be updated as you wanted it to be:

```
driver.page_source
```